# How to connect Terraform and Ansible together?

Tags: azure, ansible, terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I have written a Terraform script to spin-up an infrastructure on Azure. I have also written an Ansible script to patch the VMs launched on Azure with latest updates. But when I am not able to automate the process of patching the VMs once they get launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Provisioners in Terraform  to execute Ansible Playbooks on Provisioned VM. I'm not sure about your terraform Version. But below code might help. Keep in mind Provisioners are to be used as last resort

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ansible-playbook -u user -i '${self.public_ip},' --private-key ${var.ssh_key_private} provision.yml" 
  }
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html

Comment: `ansible-playbook not found` when trying to run it with terraform cloud, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To have end-to-end automation in which the Ansible is run when the instances are launched (and/or at every restart) you can pass in [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) configuration from Terraform. This is nice because that config may be referencing other parts of your infrastructure which can be sorted out by Terraform's dependency resolution. You would do this by providing Terraform [cloudinit_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudinit_config) to the [custom_data](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#custom_data) argument of the Azure VM in Terraform.

On the Ansible side you can also use the Azure [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_inventory.html). With this dynamic inventory you add tags to your resources in Terraform in such a way that they can be filtered and grouped into the Ansible inventory when Ansible is run. This is helpful if the Ansible tasks need to gather facts from hosts.

Comment: So how to automate this configuration using ansible and terraform together when we need to use ssh key for ansible ?